# find bigrams in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nlp, nltk

I have a DataFrame with 4 columns: 'Headline', 'Body_ID', 'Stance', 'articleBody', with 'Headline' and 'articleBody containing cleaned and tokenized words.  I want to find bi-grams using nltk and have this so far:

```
bigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
articleBody_biGram_finder = df_2['articleBody'].apply(lambda x: BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(x))
```

I'm having trouble with the last step of applying the `articleBody_biGram_finder` with `bigram_measures`. I've tried multiple iterations of lambda with list comprehension but am getting nowhere.

my most recent attempts:

`df_2['articleBody_scored'] = score_ngrams(bigram_measures.raw_freq) for item in articleBody_biGram_finder`

`df_2['articleBody_scored'] = articleBody_biGram_finder.apply(lambda x: BigramCollocationFinder.score_ngrams(bigram_measures.raw_freq))`

Answer (score 0):

`df_2['bigram_scored'] = df_2['bigram_finder'].apply(lambda x: x.score_ngrams(bigram_measures.raw_freq))`